# How to pause a MySQL database transaction in NodeJS (expressJS)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, transactions

So I was given a coding challenge where a long database transaction has been initiated by a user (say a database update of some 2 million entries), but say the user accidently updates 20 million entries (maybe he took all entries from Jan 2017 to Jan 2019 when he was supposed to take entries from Jan 2018 to June 2018), so the user has initiated a transaction that takes a lot of time in the database. The challenge is to implement a feature to allow the user to pause, cancel or resume the update. I have attached the code I have as of now in my server.js file.

```
function getDataForDateRange(res, dateLowerBound, dateUpperBound, updateValue) {
    /* Begin transaction */
    connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
        console.log('Transaction will begin...')
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ', err);
            throw err;
        }

        connection.query('UPDATE sakila.customer SET ? WHERE create_date >= ? AND create_date <= ?', [{ active: uVal }, dateLB, dateUB], function (err, result) {
            console.log('query started.');
            if (err) {
                connection.rollback(function () {
                    console.log('ERROR, database transaction rolled back.')
                    throw err;
                });
            }


            em.addListener('pause', function () {
                console.log('Event Listener pause request callback called.');
                // I want to wait until resume event happens

                // pause the database transaction here. How do I do that?

                em.addListener('resume', function () {
                    //connection.resume() --> find a function which can do this?
                    console.log('Connection resumed');
                });
                console.log('done waiting for resume button press');
            });

            //cancel event listener
            em.addListener('cancel', function () {
                connection.rollback(function () {
                    console.log('CANCELLED transaction upon user request');
                    console.log('transaction has been rolled back due to user cancelling transaction.');
                });
            });

            connection.commit(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw err;
                });
            }
            console.log('successfully committed');
        });

        });
    });
    /* End transaction */
}
```

I have used event emitters named 'pause', 'cancel' and 'resume' in the REST API end point, which will be raised everytime those requests are made by the user. I guess the cancel logic is pretty straightforward, as there I just have to rollback and close the connection, but I am struggling with the pause and resume feature. How would you pause a database transaction? And then also have the option of resuming from where you paused?

P.S: Are there any better approaches to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you edit your question to reduce your code example to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue? Also, please add some of the things you've tried, and how they worked out.

Comment: Hey, I've edited it to the main function code. Is that more concise? Let me know if any more details would be helpful. I did run this code but the dataset I am using is not nearly as big as 2 million entries, so when I try to cancel the transaction, it has always has already comitted and completed. The cancel seems to be working fine, I just want to find a way to actually pause the transaction while its happening, and then have a way of continuing from the paused state once the resume event occurs.

Comment: Once you have sent a query to the server, the server runs it. And the server doesn't allow you to pause execution of a query, so your feature isn't supported. You can however decide to not commit it afterwards, e.g. decide to either wait/pause or rollback/cancel depending on the button state (your code is currently missing a `connection.commit` though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure that this is the best answer, you could try the following:

1. Turn off autocommit
2. Start the transaction
3. Instead of running a conditional update with a date range, you could try running an update based on id. That way you can monitor what item you updated, by maybe storing them in a list
4. Query your server for the status of your transaction (in progress, completed etc)
5. If you want to pause the transaction, just stop running update for a while (maybe using a boolean flag)
6. If you want to abort the transaction, simply send the ROLLBACK command
7. Once you're happy with your transaction, COMMIT it.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I did follow the steps you mentioned, however, due to the nature of nodejs, I was unable to find a way to implement the boolean flag (something like isPaused or isResumed). Due to the asynchronous event-driven nature of node, I went for using worker threads. I put the transaction in a new worker thread. The connection would be made in the worker thread. If the user clicks on pause/cancel/resume, the main thread is listening for these events and will send a message through the message channel to the worker thread which will then pause/resume/cancel the connection.